# Concrete5 Community Store (Square) not processing payment as an integer

Tags: casting, concrete5

This error is occurring each time I try to put a payment through.

Log shows:

> JSON from response body:
>   {"errors":[{"category":"INVALID_REQUEST_ERROR","code":"EXPECTED_INTEGER","detail":"Expected
>   an integer value.","field":"amount_money.amount"}]}

I modified line 123 of CommunityStoreSquarePaymentMethod.php from:

```
        "amount" => StoreCalculator::getGrandTotal()*100,
```

to:

```
        "amount" => number_format(StoreCalculator::getGrandTotal()*100,'',''),
```

This gave me the error:

> Exception Occurred:
>   /public_html/packages/community_store_square/src/CommunityStore/Payment/Methods/CommunityStoreSquare/CommunityStoreSquarePaymentMethod.php:123
>   number_format() expects parameter 2 to be integer, string given (2)

So it looks like it's being read as a string instead of an integer. What's the best way to rectify this?  I've tried set_type but not sure I understand how to use it as it returns a boolean.

Comment: I don't know if mesuva (the author of Community Store) monitors stackoverflow questions. You could try to ask in the #ecommerce channel on Slack - see https://www.concrete5.org/slack

Comment: Thanks, will check there.  I was able to just cast using (int) before the send of data, which seems to have worked!  Will question this in slack though, just in case this hits anyone else (or a better solution is needed).

Comment: @James Korden: Your second exception says, that your second parameter is a string, look at your code, it is `''`, where it should be the decimals as integer. Use it like `"amount" => number_format(StoreCalculator::getGrandTotal()*100, 0)` to get no decimal or `"amount" => number_format(StoreCalculator::getGrandTotal()*100, 2)` to get 2 decimals. Looking into the manual it states: _This function accepts either one, two, or four parameters (not three)_, see https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php.